# Filtering multiple values using array in Autofilter VBA filters rows with only first value

Tags: vba, autofilter

I feel like I am making some small error somewhere and could use a hand with this.
I have read other StackOverflow posts about similar topics but not quite what I am encountering.
I have an array that has certain string values. The length of this array is dynamic in nature. When I am passing this array to my AutoFilter it is filtering the rows based only on the first value of the array and not the rest. The array values are derived from a range of cells as can be seen in the code snippet below.

```
Dim arr() As Variant
arr() = desWS.Range("F3:F" & lastreg).Value
regWS.Range("A2:AE" & lastRow).AutoFilter 6, arr(), xlFilterValues
```

What it does is that it filters all the values in regWS with only the first value in the arr().
I have made sure that the array does in fact contains these values but have no idea as to why it is not filtering for all values and could not find anything relevant to this. Please suggest something. Thank you.

Comment: Please, try `arr() = Application.Transpose(desWS.Range("F3:F" & lastreg).Value)`. You need to use a 1D array... Or create the array as you try, but use it as: `regWS.Range("A2:AE" & lastRow).AutoFilter 6, Application.Transpose(arr()), xlFilterValues`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand good, you want to filter a table from the cell A2 to the cell of the lastrow of column AE. Try to use this macro:

```
Sub Filtrer_column_1_to_5_according_to_second_row_of_column_6()

    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AE$" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Range("F2")

End sub
```

I suppose that your criteria to filter is always in the cell F2.